# Por que “h” é usado para altura na matemática?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Na matemática, usa-se *h* para representar a altura, como na fórmula do triângulo (*A* = (*hb*)/2), mas por que se usa *h* para representar **a**ltura?

Um responderia que é porque “altura” em inglês é “**h**eight”, mas o inglês é uma lingua franca econômica há pouco, há menos ainda científica.

Comment: Também é h no francês *hauteur* e no alemão *hohe*.

Comment: @Jacinto, faria sentido, já que o francês e o alemão já forma línguas científicas.

Comment: Foi mais ou menos o que eu pensei. Entre o inglês, o francês e o alemão, temos o grosso da produção científica dos últimos 200 anos. Mas a área do triângulo é geometria elementar; não é produção científica dos últimos 200 anos.

Comment: Mas, @Jacinto , a maior parte dos textos em português sobre o assunto foi escrita nos últimos 200 anos, então essa influência europeia e americana bastaria para explicar o uso do "h".

Answer (score 3):

Embora não seja um símbolo estabelecido, de fato é comum usar "h" para denotar altura, especialmente em [física](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_physics_notations) e matemática básica (embora o símbolo não costume constar em listas de símbolos matemáticos, como [esta](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/) ou [esta](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Mathematical_symbols)).

Além do inglês *height*, também em alemão, *Höhe*, e em francês, *hauteur*, "altura" começa com "h" e nelas também se [costuma](https://lexique.netmath.ca/hauteur/) usar esse símbolo para denotar a grandeza "altura" — portanto parece plausível que esta seja a origem do uso do símbolo.

Os usos mais antigos desse uso que encontrei numa busca cursiva em alemão e francês foi em [1904](http://www.zeno.org/Lueger-1904/A/Mathematische+Zeichen) ([facsímile](http://www.zeno.org/Lueger-1904/K/lueger-1904-061-0335)) e [1843](https://archive.org/stream/annalesdestrava19publgoog/annalesdestrava19publgoog_djvu.txt) ([facsímile](https://archive.org/details/annalesdestrava19publgoog/page/240/mode/2up)) respectivamente.

Outra possibilidade, aventada pelo OP nos comentários, é que o uso do "h" remonte ao [grego antigo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%95%CF%88%CE%BF%CF%82): ὕψος (/hýp.sos/, "altura"), como encontrado em Os Elementos de Euclides ([e-print](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/books/Euclid/Elements.pdf) da tradução paralela por R. Fitzpatrick), mas não encontrei evidências que apoiem essa ideia.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131285/discussion-on-answer-by-stafusa-por-que-h-e-usado-para-altura-na-matematica).